# Why i can't use BOOL variable in dynamic-input block?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have a function which can execute a task block with a callback :

```
typedef void (^TaskCallback)();
typedef void (^Task)(TaskCallback task_callback);

void execute(Task task, TaskCallback task_callback)
{
    task(task_callback);    
}
```

The TaskCallback block works fine with dynamic parameters, for example :

```
TaskCallback callback = ^ (int a, int b) {
    NSLog(@"a = %i b = %i", a, b);
};

Task task = ^ (TaskCallback callback) {
    callback(4, 2);
};

task(callback);

The output is : a = 4 b = 2
```

But when i pass a BOOL variable to TaskCallback block :

```
TaskCallback callback = ^ (int a, BOOL b) {
    NSLog(@"a = %i b = %i", a, b);
};

Task task = ^ (TaskCallback callback) {
    callback(4, NO);
};

task(callback);
```

The compiler treat it as an error :

```
incompatible block pointer types initializing 'TaskCallback' (aka 'void (^)()') with an    expression of type 'void (^)(int, BOOL)'
    TaskCallback callback = ^ (int a, BOOL b) {
                 ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've tried many cases, once add a BOOL variable in block args, i'll get the error.

---

*Seems that all less-than-32-bit data types are not supported, such as `BOOL` `float` `char` `short` `int8_t` `uint16_t` etc

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the input parameters to `TaskCallback` as being `int, BOOL`. I'm not sure why using `int, int` works*, because you've declared `TaskCallback` to be a block that accepts no input arguments. There's probably an answer to that question in the language specification, but if you want to use inputs for your callback block, you have to specify them in the block declaration.

`typedef void (^TaskCallback)(int a, BOOL b);`

*The closest I can get find to an answer is the following from the [LLVM language specification for blocks](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html):

> A Block that takes no arguments must specify void in the argument list
>   [voidarg.c]. An empty parameter list does not represent, as K&R
>   provide, an unspecified argument list.

So I'm guessing an empty parameter declaration defaults to a variable number of integers, which is why your `int, int` block works, but any other declaration will be a type mismatch.

Comment: Declare a block with `void (^block)()` means the block accept dynamic inputs, u can input anything u want. Use `void (^block)(void)` can force a block with no inputs.

Comment: See my edit, straight from the language specification.

Comment: Thx for the link. I've tried object as input, it works too. Really strange `TaskCallback callback = ^ (id a, id b) {NSLog(@"a = %p b = %@", a, b);};`